# Conditional write in dynamodb under node.js and lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to conditionally write a document to dynamodb, with the intention of "marking" the specific event as "already happened" by checking if the item exists and if not writing it.
So basically I want to check for the existence of a combination of attributes, and if there is no item with those attribute combination, write it.

I have a dynamodb instance, with a lambda function setup to write an event to it.  The table name is events and the primary key is mapId.

I have the following code:

```js
...
var params = {
  Item: {
    event: query.event,
    mapId: query.mapId
  },
  TableName: TABLE_NAME
};

params.Item.uniqueKey = query.uniqueKey;
params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
  ":mapId": query.mapId,
  ":uniqueKey": query.uniqueKey
};
params.ConditionExpression = "mapId <> :mapId and uniqueKey <> :uniqueKey";
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
...
```

I am expecting this code to succeed the first time, but fail the second time because there's already an item with the combination of attributes, however, any call to this put request adds another item with the same attributes.

I'm sure there's a way to properly do that, just haven't figured out how.  Help???

Comment: Does your table also have a range key or only a hash key?

Comment: it only has a hash key